# google maps: cannot scroll on mobile

Tags: google-maps, mobile

I am using google maps on my web site. It works perfectly fine in all browsers, however I have problem using it on mobile: I cannot scroll the map. I am suspecting that it is caused by eventListener "click", might it be the case? I am placing marker in the place where user clicked.
Here is the code:

```
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=${Locale.getDefault()}" type="text/javascript"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
     createMap();
});


function createMap(){

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55.783234,12.518363);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    makeMarker(event.latLng, true);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's not a very good idea to use Google Maps on a mobile device.